# On a result by Rubin on elementary equivalence of homeomorphism groups and homeomorphisms of the underlying spaces

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, set-theory, gn.general-topology, model-theory

In the known paper *On the reconstruction of topological spaces from their group of homeomorphisms* by Matatyahu Rubin several deep reconstruction theorems of the form "if $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces in a broad class of spaces $K$ and there is an isomorphism between $\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Homeo}(Y)$, then $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic" are proved. Moreover the following result is claimed

> Assume $V=L$. If $X$ and $Y$ are second countable connected Euclidean manifolds and $\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$ is elementary equivalent to $\mathrm{Homeo}(Y)$, then $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.

to appear in *Second  countable  connected  manifolds  with  elementarily  equivalent  homeomorphism groups  are  homeomorphic  in the constructible  universe*. Unfortunately I cannot find any information on a paper with this title online. Has a proof of this theorem been published by Rubin? What is known about this result in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without extra set theoretic assumptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a new paper that proves something even stronger for compact manifolds: https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.01481. I don't know about noncompact manifolds, though, and it seems neither do the authors.